# Reference to a class in java

Tags: java, class, reference

Is it possible to store a reference to a class in java(for example `String`), similar to python:
Java:

```
class Cl {
    //
}

ArrayList<somethinghere> a;
a.add(Cl);
```

Python

```
class Cl:
    pass

A=[Cl]
```

Comment: You probably want to use `Cl.class`. This could be stored in a `List<Class<?>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
 Class<String> clazz = String.class
 Class<Cl> clazz2 = Cl.class;
 List<Class<Cl>> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.add(clazz2);
```

Comment: How do i access the methods (like constructor) of a class stored in a reference. Simply doing `clazz()` gives some errors

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance for your class using the static field `class`.

In your case  `Cl.class` is the value you want.

This can be stored in a variable of type `Class<?>` or in a `List<Class<?>>`

```
Class<?> clazz = Test.class;
```